# Asp.net mvc3 displaying model propy item names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display `model` Property names in my `View` instead of values.

For example if my `model` has properties `name` , `address` and `phone` as properties, I want to display the same property names in my view. Could you please let me know how to do that?

What I tried is I stepped into the code in debug mode and saw `Model[0]` item and found all property names there and I am struck from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{

    @propertyInfo.Name
}
```

Comment: This is great code Rajesh, but it even picks the DisplayName attributes. I am struggling hard to restrict display name attributes from the list. Could you please give some idea?

Comment: @Usham Just don't use `Label` or `Editor`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can just use `Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` as, unless you have specified display names for these properties, they will default to the property name.